# Keeping an element position fixed while applying a border

Tags: jquery, css, position

I'm trying to create an online picture framing example. I have an image that can then be customised to show different border, mount and frame sizes. These are illustrated by adding a border to the corresponding elements that surround the image. The user can change these values and this will be shown in the preview.

Ideally, I want to keep the image centered within the containing `#preview` div and have the borders applied around it. Can this be done with CSS alone or will it require JS/jQuery?

Here's an example: http://www.peaknature.co.uk/test.php

I've tried fixing the position of the image to begin with but that leads to the containing divs all being broken.

Here's some code:

Layout:

```
<div id="preview">
<span id="frame-preview">
    <span id="mount-preview">
        <span id="border-preview">
            <span id="image-preview" class="id-number" ><img src="image.jpg" /></span>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
#preview {
    width:70%;
    min-height:300px;
    padding:20px 0;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
#frame-preview {
    outline:0px solid pink;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    top:60px;
}
#mount-preview {
    outline:0px solid green;
    display:inline-block;
}
#border-preview {
    outline:0px solid blue;
    display:inline-block;
}
#image-preview {
    display:inline-block;
}
#image-preview img {
}
```

JS:

```
        $('#border_size').change(function(event) {
            var value = $('#border_size').val();
            //alert(value);
            $("#border-preview").css({ outlineWidth: value });
        });

        $('#mount_size').change(function(event) {
            var value = $('#mount_size').val();
            //alert(value);
            $("#mount-preview").css({ outlineWidth: value });
        });

        $('#frame_size').change(function(event) {
            var value = $('#frame_size').val();
            //alert(value);
            $("#frame-preview").css({ outlineWidth: value });
        });
```

Thanks.

Comment: where is code ?????what you have tried???

Comment: you should try to use CSS property `outline` instead of `border`. Be aware of none radius support. And please consider to post relevant code in your question

Comment: @rajeshkakawat I've tried using CSS to fixed the position of the starting image element but as I've said, it break the layout of the containing divs. All the code is at the example page I created within the question.

Comment: @ChrisJ What will happen when your 'test page' will be offline? Do you think your question would be still usefull for futur readers?! So post relevant code in your question to keep track on it

Comment: @A.Wolff Fair point, I've updated my questions. Thanks.

Comment: @A.Wolff The outline is great for keeping the image in position, however, they overlap each other. I guess that the no-radius support bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
 #frame-preview {
   border: 0 solid #FFC0CB;
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks rajesh. That's kept the positioning, it'll just take a little JS to keep the layout. You've put me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

`#preview {
    width:70%;
    min-height:300px;
    padding:5px;
    margin:5px auto;
    text-align: center; 
    border:1px solid #000;
    }`

`#frame-preview {
    border:0px solid pink;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    margin:20px auto;}`